# How to load a UIViewController programmatically?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, nib

I'm trying to load a UIViewController from code.  I basically created a UIViewController generating a .xib file.  I load it with the following code:

```
testViewController = [[TestViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TestViewController" bundle:nil];
```

this works but apparently (from what I have read) only the view is kept and the controller is deallocated (something which I have tested putting a breakpoint in the UIViewController's dealloc method).  I need to keep the UIViewController or otherwise, create a UIViewController with a UIView loaded from a nib file.  How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you mean. What you're doing there is correct. Since you've allocated it, you also -need to send a release statement to the view controller at some point, till then it shouldn't be dealloc'ed.

A view might get released and set to nil under a special case where the application receives a memory warning, but I'm not sure if this was what you've read.

Comment: I think I'm getting things wrong. The UIViewController nor the UIView is being deallocated. I placed a UITableViewController inside the nib linked to the UIViewController.  That is the one being deallocated without me telling it anywhere.  
... Any ideas what could be happening?

Comment: Hmm, definitely weird. Are you able to see the table view at all ? Or does it just randomly deallocate? I'd comment out any release statements just to see if it helps. Can you post some more code / crash log?

Comment: The TableView is showing but it crashes later when the delegate (the UITableViewController) is needed again.  I am not releasing anything anywhere but in the dealloc method of the UIViewController with the UITableViewController (which is not being called).  The crash messages EXC_BAD_ACCESS as excepted (for calling a released object).